# Calling function from c++ dll whose argument is a struct and the struct's attribute is a string

Tags: java, visual-c++, jna

I know how to use the basic type such as `int`, `char*`, `struct`, but I don't know what represents the `C++` type `string` which is a class using `jna`. I used the `String` of `Java` to represent the `string` of `C++`, but errors happens, so I think maybe they are not equal. Can anybody who know help me, thanks!

public class classer {

```
public  static class sDoc extends Structure{
    public static class ByReference extends sDoc implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public String sTitle;
    public String sContent;
    public String sAuthor;
    public String sBoard;
    public String sDatatype;



}
 public interface CLibrary extends Library { 
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) 
            Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "LJClassifier" : "c"), 
                               CLibrary.class); 

        boolean classifier_init(String conf, String sLicenseCode);
        String classifier_exec(sDoc.ByReference d, int iType);
        String classifier_detail(String classname);
        void classifier_exit();
    } 





 public static void main(String[] args) { 
     if(!CLibrary.INSTANCE.classifier_init("rulelist.xml",null)) {
            System.out.print("classifier_init failed!\n");
            return ;
        }
        sDoc.ByReference d= new sDoc.ByReference();
        d.sTitle = "天翼定制手机天语E600";  
        d.sContent = "全球旅行必备:天翼定制手机天语E600 新浪 2011-9-26 15:53手机——这项人们使用率最高的电子产品,其更新换代速度更是快得无法想象。那么对于我们消费者而言,应当如何选择呢? 显然,频繁的换机是非常不划算的,更会增加生活开支,平白增添生活负担。因此,我们在购机之初就应当选择一款满足自身需求的手机。..."; 

        d.sAuthor = "飞香";
        d.sBoard = "69"; 
        d.sDatatype = "论坛";
        System.out.print("-----------------------------------------");
        **String sResult = CLibrary.INSTANCE.classifier_exec(d,0);**
        //System.out.print(sResult);


 }
```

}

//it stoped at String sResult = CLibrary.INSTANCE.classifier_exec(d,0)

Comment: See http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html at Section 3.2 :)

Comment: I think I didn't say clearly, the C++ struct type is defined as:           typedef struct _stDoc {

 string sTitle;
 string sContent;
 string sAuthor;
 string sBoard;
 string sDatatype;

}stDoc;                                                             the string is a class not a char* type, that is what I am confused

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is not directly representable in JNA.  You need a pure C interface, so you'll need to convert `std::string` to `const char*` in order to transfer data between JNA and C++.